# Getting error in GcmListenerService

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

getting this error sometime when gets any push notifications(not in every device)- it could be device issue ??
latest get crash in Android 5.0

Please help !!

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.intern()' on a null
>   object reference
>          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1556)
>          at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
>          at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getIntentSender(ActivityManagerNative.java:3740)
>          at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:291)
>          at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:252)
>          at com.mystuc.Service.MyGcmListenerService.sendNotification(MyGcmListenerService.java:122)
>          at com.mystuc.Service.MyGcmListenerService.onMessageReceived(MyGcmListenerService.java:82)
>          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzq(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzp(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)
>          at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

I am using this code:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";
private Intent intent;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    Log.e("onMessageReceived", "onMessageReceived:" + data.toString());
    Utils pref = Utils.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    String uid = pref.getString(Constants.uid, "");
    if (uid.length() > 0) {
        if (pref.getBoolean(Constants.isEnableNotification, false)) {

            try {
                String response = data.getString("data");
                if (response != null) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.has("stype")) {
                        String stype = jsonObject.getString("stype");
                        if (stype.equalsIgnoreCase("timeline")) {
                            String msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");
                            String post_type = jsonObject.getString("post_type");
                            String post_id;
                            String postDetails = "";
                            if (post_type.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.PostType.Question)) {
                                post_id = jsonObject.getString("question_id");
                            } else {
                                post_id = jsonObject.getString("post_id");
                                try {
                                    postDetails = jsonObject.getJSONArray("postDetail").getJSONObject(0).toString();
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            String post_tab = jsonObject.getString("post_tab");


                            String message = msg.trim();
                            if (post_type.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.PostType.Question)) {

                                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionView.class);
                            } else {
                                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FeedDetail_home.class);
                            }


                            intent.putExtra(Constants.fromTimeLineNotification, true);
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.posttype, post_type);
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.postid, post_id);
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.posttab, post_tab);
                            intent.putExtra(Constants.postDetailsJson, postDetails);
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                            sendNotification(message, intent);
                        }
                    } else {
                        String msg = jsonObject.getString("msg");

                        String sender = jsonObject.getString("sent_by");
                        String templeteid = jsonObject.getString("template_id");
                        String message = msg.trim();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Constants.fromNotification, true);
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        sendNotification(message, intent);
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    sendBroadcast();
}


public void sendBroadcast() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(Constants.OnNotification));
}

private void sendNotification(String message, Intent intent) {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            MyGcmListenerService.this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.app_icon);
    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
    Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mystuc/raw/coindrop");
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_smallnotify)
            .setContentTitle("MyStuC")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(color)
            .setSound(sound)
            .setLargeIcon(icon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 , notificationBuilder.build());
}}
```

Comment: Please explain your question @Gurvinder

Comment: i have added some more details, pls check. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int uniqueInt = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() & 0xfffffff);
```

Instead of giving 0 in,

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

give that uniqueint